# CakePHP 3 : payment gateway integration like instamojo

Tags: cakephp, payment-gateway, cakephp-3.2, instamojo

I want to integrate `Instamojo Payment Gateway` [[github link]](https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php) in my CakePHP 3 application.

I'm new to CakePHP. Is there any good plugin to integrate this in the application or any other way to use it.

I'm using CakePHP 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Go to instamojo Payment Gateway and login with your credential
2- Create a payment button from your account
3- Copy button (html) from Instamojo
4- Paste it in your ctp file where you want.